# Calculus problem involving recurrent sequences

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

I found this interesting problem in a Romanian magazine. I managed to show that the sequence is convergent, but I couldn't find the limit. Let $(a_n)_{n \ge 1}$ a sequence defined as follows: 
$$a_1 \gt 0$$$$ a_{n+1}= \frac {na_n} {n+a_n^2},\forall n \ge 1.$$
calculate $$ \lim _ {n \to \infty} a_n.$$
Later edit. I showed the convergence in two steps: 1) I calculated $a_{n+1}/a_n$ which is less than 1, so the sequence is strictly dereasing; 2)The terms are between $a_1$ and $0$, so it is bounded. By Weierstrass' Theorem, the sequence is convergent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This is a massive revision
of my original answer,
which sits lonely at the end.)

It converges to zero.

I am quite sure that
the true order of $a_n$
is
$\dfrac1{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{c + \log(n)}}
$.

Since
$\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}
=1+a_n^2/n
\gt 1
$,
$a_n>a_{n+1}$
so that
$\lim a_n$
exists and is non-negative.

To show that
$\lim a_n=0$,

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{a_n}{a_{n+k}}
&=\prod_{j=1}^k \dfrac{a_{n+j-1}}{a_{n+j}}\\
&=\prod_{j=1}^k (1+a_{n+j}^2/(n+j))\\
&>\sum_{j=1}^k \dfrac{a_{n+j}^2}{n+j}\\
\end{array}
$

If $\lim a_n >0$,
then
$\sum_{j=1}^k \dfrac{a_{n+j}^2}{n+j} \to \infty$
as $k \to \infty$
which makes
$\dfrac{a_n}{a_{n+k}} \to \infty$,
so
$\dfrac{a_{n+k}}{a_n} \to 0$,
a contradiction.

To estimate how
$a_n \to 0$,
suppose
$a_n \approx 1/f(n)$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}
&\approx\dfrac{f(n+1)}{f(n)}\\
&\approx\dfrac{f(n)+f'(n)}{f(n)}\\
&=1+\dfrac{f'(n)}{f(n)}\\
\end{array}
$

and
$1+\dfrac{a_n^2}{n}
\approx 1+\dfrac{1}{nf(n)^2}
$
so that we want
$\dfrac{1}{nf(n)^2}
=\dfrac{f'(n)}{f(n)}
$
or
$f'(n) f(n) = \dfrac1{n}
$.

According to Wolfy,
the solution to this is
$f(x)
= \sqrt{2} \sqrt{c + \log(x)}
$,
so that
$a_n
\approx \dfrac1{\sqrt{2} \sqrt{c + \log(n)}}
$.

---

Here is my original solution:

---

It goes to zero because
$a_{n+1}/a_n =1/(1+a_n^2/n)
<1-a_n^2/(2n)$.

If $\lim a_n >0$,
then
$\sum a_n^2/(2n)$
diverges,
which makes
$\prod a_{n+1}/a_n \to 0$,
a contradiction.

Comment: I will have a further look when I get a chance, but quite question -- shouldn't you drop the constant in the final equivalent (i.e., drop the $c$)? Assuming the $\approx$ is the usual $\sim$ (equivalence, or viewed differently first-order Taylor), then you should only end with the first-order term -- $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\log n}}$; keeping the $c$ is basically adding a higher-order term.

Comment: I put it in because that's what Wolfy gave as the solution to the differential equation. It might be interesting to see which form (Wolfy's or yours) gives a better approximation.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood what you meant by the $\approx$ sign. You want to find a (smooth enough) function $f$ which coincides with the sequence at its integer values?

Comment: Not coincide - just smooth and close.

Answer (score 4):

**A possible approach:**

1. **Prove convergence.**

   - By induction, show that $a_n > 0$ for all $n\geq 1$.
   - Observe then that $0 < \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{n}{n+a)n^2} < 1$, so that the sequence is decreasing.
   - Invoke the monotone convergence theorem: the sequence converges to some $\ell\in[0,a_1)$.
2. **Find the limit.** Suppose by contradiction that $\ell > 0$ *(the proof can be easily adapted to be done without contradiction, but then one has to be careful when taking [equivalents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Generalizations_and_related_usages) to avoid the "equivalent to $0$" issue. So I am going for a proof by contradiction for simplicity)*. Observe that
   $$
   \ln \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_1} = \ln \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}
   = \ln \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1+\frac{a_k^2}{k}}
   = -\sum_{k=1}^n\ln\left(1+\frac{a_k^2}{k}\right).
   $$
   By theorems of comparison of series, and since the sequence converges to $\ell$ (so that $\frac{a_k^2}{k}\xrightarrow[k\to\infty]{}0$) we have that 
   $$
   \sum_{k=1}^n\ln\left(1+\frac{a_k^2}{k}\right) \operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty}
   \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a_k^2}{k}\operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty}
   \ell^2 \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}\operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty}
   \ell^2 \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}
   \operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty}
   \ell^2 \ln n
   $$
   *(where for the equivalent we used that $\ell > 0$, as otherwise "equivalent to $0$" would not be formally correct in that case).*

But then,
$$
\ln \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_1} \operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} -\ell^2 \ln n \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} -\infty
$$
i.e. 
$$
\ln a_{n+1} \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} -\infty
$$
and by unicity of the limit this means that $\ell = 0$. Contradiction.

So $$\boxed{\ell=0.}$$

---

For the sake of illustration, here is a plot of the first 100 elements of the sequence, obtained with Mathematica (for $a_1\in\{1,2,3\}$):

[image]

Comment: Now, an interesting followup question would be to get the exact rate of convergence to $0$. With the above, we get that it converges quite slowly ($\frac{1}{n^{o(1)}}$), but that's still a very crude picture of what happens.

Comment: I got $a_n =\Theta(1/\sqrt{\ln(n)})$. See my answer